# TypeError: stub expected to yield, but no callback was passed. Received [[object Object]] while using sinon to mock a dynamodb get call

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sinon, stub, sinon-chai

I have a simple lambda function which makes a get call to the dynamodb. I am trying to mock this using sinon and am stuck with an error.

app.js

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

async function run(){
    const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    const params = {
        TableName: 'employees',
        Key: {
            name: "naxi"
        }
    };
    const result = await dynamoDB.get(params).promise();
    if (result.Item) {
        return result.Item;
    } else {
        return { error: 'Task not found.' };
    }
}

module.exports = {
    run
  }
```

index.spec.js

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const assert = require('assert');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('Test Suite', () => {
  let mut;
  let clientStub;

  before(() => {
    clientStub = {
      get: sinon.stub()
    }

    const awsStub = {
      DynamoDB: {
        DocumentClient: class {
          constructor() {
            return clientStub;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    mut = proxyquire('../app.js', {
      'aws-sdk': awsStub
    })
  });

  it('should get random data!', async () => {
    const expectedData = "neeraj";

    clientStub.get.yields(null, expectedData);

    const data = await mut.run();

    sinon.assert.callCount(clientStub.get, 1);
    assert.strictEqual(data, expectedData);
  });
})
```

Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha ../**/*spec.js --recursive --timeout 10000"
  }
```

Once I run the test script, I receive the below error.

```
TypeError: stub expected to yield, but no callback was passed. Received [[object Object]]
```

Can anyone please tell me what am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how i test my code using **supertest package and jest**.

In my backend, I am making a post request to send some data. Ofcourse you can skip as per your need

```
let sandbox;
describe('Test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
   // process.env.redirectBaseUrl = 'http://xxxx/'; // if you want to set
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    delete process.env.redirectBaseUrl;
    sandbox.restore();
  });
  test('should return converted url', async () => {
    const data = {
      Item: {
        convertedUrl: 'abc',
      },
    };

    sandbox
      .stub(AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'get')
      .returns({ promise: () => data });

    const app = require('../app');
    const response = await request(app)
      .post('/users/anon-user/urls')
      .send({ originalUrl: 'https://google.com' });
    expect(response.body).toMatchObject({ convertedUrl: 'abc' });

    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(201);
  });
 })
```

Comment: Now after doing some tweaks, I made it work. Thanks Jatin!

Comment: If it helped you, can you accept it as an answer so that it may help others in the future, of course feel free to edit my answer and add your tweaks

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I made it work.

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const assert = require('assert');
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

let sandbox;

describe('Test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
      });
    
    afterEach(() => {
        sandbox.restore();
    });

    it('should return something', async () => {

        const data = {
            Item: {
              convertedUrl: 'abc',
            }
          };

        sandbox
        .stub(AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient.prototype, 'get')
        .returns({ promise: () => data });

        const app = require('../app');
        const result = await app.run();
        assert.strictEqual(result, data);
    });
});
```